# Problems using two MPR121 HAT's with Pi3 and Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I wish to use several MPR121 HATs with my Raspberry Pi 3, using python 3.4.2. I am testing it using just two MPR121's.
Each MPR121 works as expected when connected by itself, with the following code, no matter what its I2C bus address is. But I cannot get the two to work together. I have tried various if not all combinations of them connected individually and together with different buss addresses. I am using the example python code given in the Adafruit tutorial. A common occurrence when both MPR121's are connected is it continuously runs through each input printing 'input touched'. So using the following code with both MPR121's connected(with different bus addresses) it continuously prints:
input 0 touched!
input 1 touched!
input 2 touched!
input 3 touched!
...and so on, continuously looping through all 12 inputs.

```
import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_mpr121

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

mpr121 = adafruit_mpr121.MPR121(i2c, address=0x5A)

while True:
    for i in range(12):
        if mpr121[i].value:
            print('Input {} touched!'.format(i))
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

With the above code and only one MPR121 connected, there is no output until an input sensor pad is touched. When a sensor pad is touched it outputs the corresponding message: (e.g. when sensor pad 1 touched)

```
Input 1 touched!
```

This is the expected behaviour. This is the same with either MPR121 connected.
With both MPR121's connected, and using the above code (address=0x5A, which is the default address), it immediately outputs the following, indefinitely:

```
Input 0 touched!
Input 1 touched!
Input 2 touched!
Input 3 touched!
Input 4 touched!
Input 5 touched!
Input 6 touched!
Input 7 touched!
Input 8 touched!
Input 9 touched!
Input 10 touched!
Input 11 touched!
Input 0 touched!
Input 1 touched!
```

and so on..

With both MPR121's connected, and using the above code, but with address=0x5B(the correct address of the second MPR121), it immediately outputs the following, indefinitely:

```
Input 2 touched!
Input 3 touched!
Input 4 touched!
Input 5 touched!
Input 6 touched!
Input 7 touched!
Input 8 touched!
Input 9 touched!
Input 10 touched!
Input 11 touched!
Input 0 touched!
Input 1 touched!
Input 2 touched!
```

and so on..

With the following code(which is part way to expanding it to work with 2 MPR121's):

```
import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_mpr121

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

mpr121_A = adafruit_mpr121.MPR121(i2c, address=0x5A)
mpr121_B = adafruit_mpr121.MPR121(i2c, address=0x5B)

while True:
    for i in range(12):
        if mpr121_A[i].value:
            print('Input {} touched!'.format(i))
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

I get the following error:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART       
================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-                                    
    packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py"line 64, in __init__
        i2c.writeto(device_address, b'')
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/busio.py", line 63,    
    in writeto
        return self._i2c.writeto(address, buffer, stop=stop)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist- 
    packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/raspi_23/i2c.py", line   
    38, in writeto
        self._i2c_bus.write_bytes(address, buffer[start:end])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-   
    packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 244, in write_bytes
        self._device.write(buf)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/pi/Desktop/Dual MPR121 test2.py", line 9, in <module>
        mpr121 = adafruit_mpr121.MPR121(i2c, address=0x5A)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/adafruit_mpr121.py",      
    line 103, in __init__
        self._i2c = i2c_device.I2CDevice(i2c, address)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-       
    packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 66, in __init__
        raise ValueError("No I2C device at address: %x" %   
    device_address)
ValueError: No I2C device at address: 5a
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Instead of the large block of text, can you show the input and output for each MPR as code blocks, separately? Then can you show the input and output for both MPRs together, as code blocks, separately? Be sure to include any other info that might help us answer your question.

Comment: I'm rather a novice, so I'm not sure, .. but I hope this is what you mean..